# base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'const JointState'

Tags: ros, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys..
I am trying to write a simple publisher and subscriber, but having some problems with my subscriber...

The message type i am using is sensor_msgs::JointState msg ([doc](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html))  for my subscriber i have this callback function.

```
void ChatterCallback(const sensor_msgs::JointState& msg){
  ROS_INFO("i've heard: " ,msg->position);
}
```

but somehow i end up getting this error message saying

> error: base operand of '->' has
> non-pointer type 'const JointState'

which just doesn't make sense for me..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203353/base-operand-of-%27-%3E%27-has-non-pointer-type-%27const-jointstate%27/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the error.

```
    void ChatterCallback(const sensor_msgs::JointState::ConstPtr& msg)
{
      ROS_INFO("i've heard: [%f]" ,msg->position[0]);
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) with karma: 156 on 2015-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is more a C++ issue: the error is telling you that the variable `msg` is not a pointer. And it isn't: it's a reference to a `JointState` object.

Edit: so replace the `->` with a `.` (dot).

Note: you can't directly pass the `position` member to `ROS_INFO(..)` though. Unlike Python, C++ doesn't have auto-conversions to strings.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3